# How to implement in drag event in android live wallpaper

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I've created an interactive live wallpaper with touch event, each time the user will touch the screen 
an animated photos will start to appear, android is using

```
@Override
public Bundle onCommand(String action, int x, int y, int z,
                        Bundle extras, boolean resultRequested) {
    if (WallpaperManager.COMMAND_TAP.equals(action)) {
    }
}
```

The problem is in `WallpaperManager` it is limited to 3 options only `COMMAND_TAP` and `COMMAND_DROP` 
and another one that i don't need which is selecting wall paper,i need to implement on drag event also,when the user move his finger all over the screen this animation 
will follow the finger drag, and i need to implement it without using openGL as some questions is solving it this way,how can i do that , please note that this question might be duplicated but i don't want to use openGL to solve it , any suggestions ?